# Max number of connections

Tags: rxandroidble

I have read that Android 4.4+ supports 7 connections open at a time. My question is: does RxAndroidBle handle queuing of connection operations when this number is reached, or is it up to the user of the library to implement a queue for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RxAndroidBle library doesn't handle queueing of connections. In fact it is quite impossible to do that since the number of connections is shared among every application in the system and not only the RxAndroidBle may be opening them.
Besides I have encountered some vendors (Micromax Canvas for instance) where despite using Android 5.0 it only worked with one connection at any given time.
Best Regards.